# Reposting: SSIS Packages In Azure Data Factory With External OData Sources

Tags: azure, ssis, odata, azure-data-factory

I'm re-posting this question because the solution in the link provided is for an on premise issue, not Azure.

[SSIS Packages In Azure Data Factory With External OData Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329770/ssis-packages-in-azure-data-factory-with-external-odata-sources?noredirect=1#comment106724929_60329770)

I am having trouble getting an SSIS package to work using Azure Data Factory. I can run the package locally in Visual Studio & also from the SSIS Catalog on my on premise server. The package has the following steps:

Pulls data from an external OData feed (SAP by Design).
Loads the data into an Azure SQL Server staging database on a DBaaS instance.
Loads the same data from Staging to a Datawarehouse on the same DBaaS instance.
Steps I have taken:

Created the SSISDB on my Azure instance.
Created an Azure Data Factory.
Created an Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime.
Created & tested a simple package to copy data from my Azure Staging database to my Azure Datawarehouse database.
Deployed the SSIS package that works on prem to Azure using an SSIS Pipeline. 
Validated the connection string in Connection Manger points to the correct OData svc URL.

The package execution on fails validation with this error:

Error: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager.

Obviously, I am missing some crucial element in my Azure set up but haven't been able to figure it out. I am very new to Azure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Just to ensure, as your ODataConnection is using basic auth - publish your package to azure ssisdb catalog only after you validate connection using Test connection method and check if it succeeds. Also check if your OData feed is reachable with basic auth just by creating the sample linked service in ADF. 
Also, it appears that it could be something with the drivers not being installed on the SSIS-IR and MS recommends to customize it if any specific drivers needs to be installed there, details here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup